# Python docker container gets empty file after bind mount in ~50% of cases

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to mount the file with the `bind` option into the container but it works very unstable.

The example below creates a file, mounts it into the container and prints the content of this file.

```
import docker
import docker.types
import tempfile

def foo():

    temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    file_path = temp_dir.name + "/file.txt"
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello")

    docker_client = docker.DockerClient()
    output = docker_client.containers.run(
        image="alpine",

        mounts=[
            docker.types.Mount("/file.txt", file_path, type="bind")
        ],
        command="cat /file.txt"
    )
    print(output)

for _ in range(10):
    foo()
```

Here are the results of the execution:

```
b''
b'Hello'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b'Hello'
b'Hello'
b'Hello'
b'Hello'
```

This random behaviour really confuses me. I have tried various options but it stil has the same results.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

UPD:

To be more clear, I should say that I have tried:

- `consistensy="consistent"` option.
- flush file and sleep after data was written in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the mounted file is not empty and containers works fine, the problem is in the unstable output of the `DockerClient.containers.run` function. What a surprise:)

Here is an example. It is not so elegant but should work.

```
import docker
import docker.types
import tempfile
import os


def foo():
    temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    file_path = temp_dir.name + "/file.txt"
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello")

    output_path = temp_dir.name + "/output"

    os.mkdir(output_path)

    docker_client = docker.DockerClient()
    docker_client.containers.run(
        image="alpine",

        mounts=[
            docker.types.Mount("/file.txt", file_path, type="bind"),
            docker.types.Mount("/output", output_path, type="bind")  # mount new directory to store copy result.
        ],
        command="cp /file.txt /output/checkfile.txt",  # copy first file into mounted directory
    )

    checkfile_path = output_path + "/checkfile.txt"

    with open(checkfile_path) as f:
        print(f.read())


for _ in range(20):
    foo()
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? Why would the output of that function be unstable?

Comment: @jakub , Because if we copy the mounted file to another file and then fetch it from the container, the content will be there.  I updated this answer, with example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file is not being written fully to disk before you run the container. If you write the file once initially and then run the container, it will print the contents every time. Here is the output in ipython:

```
In [7]: !echo "Hello" > /tmp/file.txt                                                                                                                                           

In [8]: import docker 
   ...: import docker.types 
   ...:  
   ...: def foo(file_path): 
   ...:     docker_client = docker.DockerClient() 
   ...:     output = docker_client.containers.run( 
   ...:         image="alpine", 
   ...:         mounts=[ 
   ...:             docker.types.Mount("/file.txt", file_path, type="bind") 
   ...:         ], 
   ...:         command="cat /file.txt" 
   ...:     ) 
   ...:     print(output) 
   ...:  
   ...: for _ in range(10): 
   ...:     foo("/tmp/file.txt") 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                         
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
b'Hello\n'
```

---

This is odd, however, because forcing a write to disk does not solve the problem. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsync

```py
In [1]: import docker 
   ...: import docker.types 
   ...: import tempfile 
   ...: import os 
   ...:  
   ...: def foo(): 
   ...:  
   ...:     temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() 
   ...:     file_path = temp_dir.name + "/file.txt" 
   ...:     with open(file_path, "w") as f: 
   ...:         f.write("Hello") 
   ...:         f.flush()  # Added. 
   ...:         os.fsync(f.fileno())  # Added. 
   ...:  
   ...:     docker_client = docker.DockerClient() 
   ...:     output = docker_client.containers.run( 
   ...:         image="alpine", 
   ...:  
   ...:         mounts=[ 
   ...:             docker.types.Mount("/file.txt", file_path, type="bind") 
   ...:         ], 
   ...:         command="cat /file.txt" 
   ...:     ) 
   ...:     print(output) 
   ...:  
   ...: for _ in range(10): 
   ...:     foo() 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                         
b''
b''
b''
b'Hello'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b'Hello'
```

Comment: Just for the sake of making sure the tests are the same, it's worth repeating with the same folders. Right now there's at least one difference I see: you have `/tmp` in the first case and whatever `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` returns in the second case.

Comment: Because I am using linux, `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` creates a directory in `/tmp` like `/tmp/tmpak9wwrnf`